# Is there a way to have a leapmotion python script running in a background windows terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, leap-motion, windows-terminal

Usually in the case of running Python files in there terminal (in my case, Window's cmd), the Python file will run normally when you minimize the window, switch to another application, etc. However, when I have a leapmotion python script running (even just the [Sample.py](https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/devguide/Sample_Tutorial.html) provided) and I switch to another app, the script no longer runs until I un-minimize the script.

Is there some sort of setting within leapmotion or python trick to circumvent this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Best wishes, and thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found the solution. I simply needed to do the following. I wish it was a bit easier to find within the documentation, but hopefully this saves someone else some time!

```
controller.set_policy(Leap.Controller.POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES)
```